# How to setup an AWS Elastic Beanstalk Worker Tier Environment + Cron + Django for periodic tasks? 403 Forbidden error

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, cron, server

The app needs to run periodic tasks on the background to delete expired files. The app is up and running at a Web Server and at a Worker Tier Environment.

A **cron.yaml** file is at the root of the app:

```
version: 1
cron:
 - name: "delete_expired_files"
   url: "/networks_app/delete_expired_files"
   schedule: "*/10 * * * *"
```

The cron url points to an app **view**:

```
def delete_expired_files(request):
    users = DemoUser.objects.all()
    for user in users:
        documents = Document.objects.filter(owner=user.id)
        if documents:
            for doc in documents:
                now = timezone.now()
                if now >= doc.date_published + timedelta(days=doc.owner.group.valid_time):
                    doc.delete()
```

the Django **ALLOWED_HOSTS** setting is as follows:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost', 'networksapp.elasticbeanstalk.com']
```

the task is being scheduled and the queries are sending the requests to the right url, however they're going to the **WorkerDeadLetterQueue**

The Worker Tier Environment Log File shows an **403** error:

> "POST /networks_app/delete_expired_files HTTP/1.1" 403 1374 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.0"

The task is not being executed (expired files aren't being deleted). However when I access the url it executes the task properly.

I need to make it work automatically and periodically.

My **IAM** user has this Policies:

> AmazonSQSFullAccess
>
> AmazonS3FullAccess
>
> AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
>
> AdministratorAccess
>
> AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess

Why isn't the task being executed? Does this has to do with any *IAM* permission? Is there any missing configuration? How to make it work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you hook up this view as a handler for POSTs, or just GETs?